# QTime how to add/substract time QT/C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtime

I'm trying to add/substract time in a QTime object.

```
QString time = "10:00:00";
QTime tobj = QTime::fromString(currentTime,"hh:mm:ss");
tobj.addSecs(3600);
qDebugs() << "time:" << tobj;
```

I would expect the debugger to output "11:00:00", but it just stays "10:00:00", why is this and what am i over looking?

Comment: `addSecs()` is a const function: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#addSecs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#addSecs) It does not modify the object but returns a new QTime object.

Comment: use `tobj = tobj.addSecs(3600)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `addSecs()` is a const function: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#addSecs It does not modify the object but returns a new QTime object.

One way to solve this is to do the following:

```
QString time = "10:00:00";
QTime tobj = QTime::fromString(time,"hh:mm:ss").addSecs(3600);
qDebugs() << "time:" << tobj;
```

Here I chained the output of `QTime::fromString(time,"hh:mm:ss")` with your call to `addSecs(3600)` the value set to `tobj` will be 1 hour ahead of the time.

Comment: Thanx that makes sense!

Comment: I have found that signature beneficial in some of my use cases with the time and date classes particularly when I am dealing with multiple offsets from some date or time.